# Overlapping Report Items Causing Dataset Failure

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that consists of two graphs, with two separate datasets. They are overlapped and displayed or hidden based on a parameter on the report.

When tested in Visual Studio the report displays and runs fine (although a warning about overlapping report items is thrown), but when deployed to to our production setting, the report fails and throws an error that the Query failed for the Dataset that is hidden.

For example, datasets are WOs and WOsByAsset. When WOs is selected for display the error is Query Execution Failed for dataset WOsByAsset. When WOsByAsset is selected for display the error is Query Execution Failed for dataset WOs.

I have confirmed that both datasets work in SSMS, no actual errors are presented.

Could the fact that the graphs are overlapping cause this issue? The pattern of the errors appears to indicate that but I'd like any confirmation, or better yet, explanation that anyone may be able to give.

Comment: I doubt that the overlapping objects have anything to do with the issue. Make a copy of your report and remove the working chart and dataset. My bet is that you will get the same error.

Comment: You may have used more than one data field name in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the suggestions.

Problem was of my own making. I had not taken into account that the report runs for each dataset even when the datasets related table was hidden. The report used a multivalue parameter, and by default passed all possible choices within the parameter into the report.

This was causing that dataset to fail, but when I tested the query in ssms I was only passing a single value for which the query ran just fine.

All good here.